# what is best way to use multiple or nested ternary operator with ng-class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

May be someone very good at catching the issue, but couldn't able to find what is the issue with my nested ternary operator.

```
.class1 {background-color: red}
.class2 {background-color: yellow}
.class3 {background-color: green}
```

summary.html

```
 <p ng-class = "{(notPaid || orderCancelled) ? 'class1' : 
                   (paid && shippingInProgress) ? 'class2' : 
                   (paid && deliverd) ? 'class3' : null}" >
    </p>
```

I don't understand where am doing wrong here. Getting

**Error: [$parse:syntax]**

someone pls help me on this

Answer (score 0):

I never used angularJs but according to docs, it should be like this.

```html
 <p ng-class = "{ 'class1': (notPaid || orderCancelled), 'class2': (paid && shippingInProgress),
                   'class3': (paid && deliverd)}" >
  </p>

<!--- if you don't want a clean solution here is your working code. -->

<p ng-class = "(notPaid || orderCancelled) ? 'class1' : 
                   (paid && shippingInProgress) ? 'class2' : 
                   (paid && deliverd) ? 'class3' : ''" >
    </p>
```

Comment: do you have any idea why my nested ternary throws error? or mine is totally fault ?

Comment: you should not use `{` and `}` if you are writing a js expression

Comment: @Mr.Learner I think you didn't closed the expression "}"

Comment: i've closed it @souravsatyam

Comment: try this `<p ng-class = "(notPaid || orderCancelled) ? 'class1' : 
                   (paid && shippingInProgress) ? 'class2' : 
                   (paid && deliverd) ? 'class3' : ''" >
    </p>`

Answer (score 0):

Below are the syntax of ng-class with two class one and two.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.one = 2;
});
```

```css
.one {
  color: red;
}

.two {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>





<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div ng-class="{one: (one === 1), two: (one === 2)}">
   Helllo
</div>
```